Proving $(A \land B) \to C \implies (A \to C) \lor (B \to C)$ Using Natural Deduction
I’m working on a proof in propositional logic to show that:
$$
(A \land B) \to C \implies (A \to C) \lor (B \to C)
$$
using natural deduction. I’m attempting to use a proof by contradiction, but I’m having trouble concluding the disjunction cleanly. Here's what I've done so far:

What I’ve Tried:

Premise:
$$(A \land B) \to C.$$

Assume the negation of the conclusion for a proof by contradiction:
$$
   \neg ((A \to C) \lor (B \to C)).
   $$

By applying De Morgan's Law, I break this down:
$$
   \neg ((A \to C) \lor (B \to C)) \equiv \neg (A \to C) \land \neg (B \to C).
   $$

From the negated implications, I derive:

$\neg (A \to C)$, which is equivalent to $A \land \neg C$.
$\neg (B \to C)$, which is equivalent to $B \land \neg C$.


From these statements:

From $A \land \neg C$, I extract $A$ and $\neg C$.
From $B \land \neg C$, I extract $B$ and $\neg C$.


I combine $A$ and $B$ using $\land$-introduction to derive:
$$
   A \land B.
   $$

Using the premise $(A \land B) \to C$ and $A \land B$, I apply $\to$-elimination to derive:
$$
   C.
   $$

At this point, I now have both $C$ and $\neg C$, which leads to a contradiction:
$$
   \bot.
   $$

Since assuming $\neg ((A \to C) \lor (B \to C))$ led to a contradiction, I discharge the assumption and conclude:
$$
   (A \to C) \lor (B \to C).
   $$



Where I'm Stuck:
My reasoning seems correct so far, but I’m unsure about the formal presentation of the final step where I discharge the assumption $\neg ((A \to C) \lor (B \to C))$. Specifically, I want to make sure I’m applying the rules of natural deduction correctly to conclude $(A \to C) \lor (B \to C)$.
Is there a cleaner or more rigorous way to write this proof formally? Any feedback or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Why is this question being downvoted?  The OP shows work, effort, and has a clear question. It’s also nicely typeset, explained, and organized.  The wanton downvoting on this site is getting to be really off-putting, especially with no explanation given.

We don't have the rules for your natural deduction system.  I don't see how we could determine if you used those rules correctly or not.  In the literature, there does exist different rules for different systems of natural deduction.

Are you sure the system you're working with has rules for De Morgan's laws and rewriting implications? Most formulations of natural deduction don't. It would be helpful if you showed us the exact set of rules you're allowed to use because they differ between different presentations.

You can't actually prove this in natural deduction.  To prove it in natural deduction you would have to know which of the two conclusions are true, which is no possible in general.  It is possible to prove it in classical propositional logic though.

The rule you are using in the end is negation introduction
$$
\frac{\begin{bmatrix}X \\ \vdots \\ \bot \end{bmatrix}}{\neg X}
$$
where $X = \neg ((A \to C) \lor (B \to C))$, followed by double negation elimination
$$
\frac{\neg \neg Y}{Y}
$$
where $Y = ((A \to C) \lor (B \to C))$. So the conclusion under your first assumption is $((A \to C) \lor (B \to C))$. You can then apply implication introduction to complete the proof.
In terms of clarity and rigour, you can always draw a proof tree, for example like this. On the left you write your assumptions and conclusions, and on the right the justifications.

I think that the system OP is using actually uses Indirect Proof, namely if $\neg A$ can be shown to lead to a contradiction, then we can discharge the assumption and infer $A$.

@PW_246 "Indirect proof" is exactly negation introduction followed by double negation elimination. This is also known as proof by contradiction, as OP said.

That they’re logically equivalent over some other rules doesn’t mean that they’re the same rule. For instance, both negation intro and double negation elim can be derived from indirect proof.

After assuming ¬((A → C) ∨ (B → C)), you arrive at ¬¬((A → C) ∨ (B → C)) due to the contradiction, from which you eliminate the double negation.
Note that you included some unnecessary steps (such as extracting ¬C from B ∧ ¬C). Here is the formal representation of a full natural deduction proof by contradiction:
Problem: ((A & B) > C) |- ((A > C) v (B > C))

1   |_  ((A & B) > C)              Premise
2   | |_  ~((A > C) v (B > C))     Assumption
3   | |   (~(A > C) & ~(B > C))    2  (DeM2)
4   | |   ~(A > C)                 3  &E
5   | |   (A & ~C)                 4  (NegImp)
6   | |   ~(B > C)                 3  &E
7   | |   (B & ~C)                 6  (NegImp)
8   | |   A                        5  &E
9   | |   B                        7  &E
10  | |   (A & B)                  8,9  &I
11  | |   C                        1,10  >E
12  | |   ~C                       5  &E
13  | |   #                        11,12  #I
14  |   ~~((A > C) v (B > C))      2-13  ~I
15  |   ((A > C) v (B > C))        14  ~E

The proof can be imported into https://mrieppel.github.io/fitchjs/ for automated validation and a prettier view.
